# Should I use self. when releasing

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have a whole bunch of `@property (nonatomic, retain)` stuff going on when I'm defining my variables and i want to know:

In my `dealloc` method, should i release them `[myGreatVariable release];` or `[self.myGreatVariable release];`. They are currently done in the former way. And how much does this really matter? Is it just good to get in the habit of doing this from now on, or should I go back and change all of them in all of my classes because things aren't actually getting released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in dealloc it doesn't matter, though the former is an itty bit more efficient.  But you have the 3rd option of doing `self.myFairlyGoodVariable = nil;`, which relies on the setter method to do the release (though two or three itty bits less efficiently).

I suspect you'll find different arguments for what you should do.  Some folks argue you should use the instance variable (sans `self.`) for all read accesses.  Others will argue that you should use the property access (ie, with `self.`) pretty much everywhere.  I tend to fall into the latter camp, but I could accept arguments from the other side.

It's important to be reasonably consistent, though.  And if you work with others it's good if you can have a team "standard" for this.

(One thing I like to do is to put the `dealloc` method at the top of the .m file, vs at the bottom where it usually ends up.  This way you will be more likely to remember to update the `dealloc` method when you add/change a property and the associated `@synthesize` statement.)

Comment: "Some folks argue you should use the instance variable (sans `self.`) for all read accesses." why and when would you ever want to do this (except in dealloc, of course)? I know you said you dont agree with that but why would anyone ever want to not use `self.` when you are accessing or setting? why does that even work?

Comment: Well, it's slightly more efficient, plus it's fewer characters to type.  And I think there's an emotional belief that it indicates that the variable is "yours" vs belonging to someone else, or something along those lines.  But mostly it's just fewer characters to type, and all programmers are inherently lazy (or else they would have gone into banking or real estate or something).

Comment: It has nothing to do with "fewer characters to type" but with avoiding entanglements with KVO in `dealloc` and `init`, as noted by EricS. /cc @josherick

Comment: I've been a programmer for 40 years.  Trust me -- it has a lot to do with being fewer characters to type.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `[self.myGreatVariable release]`. As Daniel notes, it will work in this context, but it is the most "bastardized" version, and would do the *wrong* thing anywhere outside `-dealloc` by likely leaving around a garbage reference in a property.

You should choose one of, and standardize on, either:

1. `[myGreatVariable release];`
2. `self.myGreatVariable = nil;`

(The choice is largely a personal preference. I only use the first form in `dealloc`, because setters are sometimes nontrivial and have side-effects, and the goal of `dealloc` is to get efficiently and clearly get rid of all the resources, not to get tripped up with accidental state changes.)

Comment: Yeah, in general, unless you're trying to keep the external interface "clean" of "internal" properties, it's best to avoid ever doing an explicit release of a retained property, but instead assign nil when you want to release it.

Answer (score 1):

The one problem with using "self.variable = nil" in dealloc is that it can trigger additional actions if you have overridden "setVariable". For example, some classes will signal a delegate whenever a variable changes values but you probably don't want to do that once you are in dealloc. It's a bit safer to use "[variable release]".

Hopefully ARC will make all of this go away soon.

Comment: Precisely; and a good reason to make accessors clean of side effects like this.  Better to use KVO.  Therefore in the `dealloc` method, you remove yourself as an observer first, then you're free to use the `self.variable = nil;` without worrying about side effects